# É possível redirecionar uma pagina e enviar um valor de um campo ao mesmo tempo em jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Precisava obter um valor de um select option clicado e enviar para uma outra pagina, só que eu gostaria de estar redirecionando para essa mesma pagina. Estou usando jQuery da biblioteca mobile, abaixo segue meu código em jQuery e o option:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#select-native-fc").change(function(){ 
        var val = $("#select-native-fc").val(); 
        if($(".assy") && val == "1"){
            //alert("teste");
            window.location="time1.php";
        }
    }); 
}); 
</script>

</head>

<body>
<center>
<label for="slider2"></label>
<select name="slider2" id="slider2" data-role="slider">
  <option value="pkg">PKG</option>
  <option value="assy">ASSY</option>
</select>
</center>
<div class="ui-field-contain">  
    <label for="select-native-fc">Linhas de Assembly:</label>
    <select name="select-native-fc" id="select-native-fc" class="assy">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <option value="1">Assembly 1</option>
        <option value="2">Assembly 2</option>       
        <option value="3">Assembly 3</option>
        <option value="4">Assembly 4</option>
        <option value="5">Assembly 5</option>
        <option value="6">Assembly 6</option>
        <option value="7">Assembly 7</option>
        <option value="8">Assembly 8</option>
        <option value="9">Assembly 9</option>
        <option value="10">Assembly 10</option>
        <option value="X">Assembly X</option>
        <option value="Y">Assembly Y</option>
        <option value="Z">Assembly Z</option>

    </select>
</div>



<div class="ui-field-contain">  
    <label for="select-native-fc">Linhas de Packing:</label>
    <select name="select-native-fc" id="select-native-fc" class="pkg">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <option value="1">Packing 1</option>
        <option value="2">Packing 2</option>
        <option value="3">Packing 3</option>
        <option value="4">Packing 4</option>
        <option value="5">Packing 5</option>
        <option value="6">Packing 6</option>
        <option value="7">Packing 7</option>
        <option value="8">Packing 8</option>
        <option value="9">Packing 9</option>
        <option value="10">Packing 10</option>
        <option value="X">Packing X</option>
        <option value="Y">Packing Y</option>
        <option value="Z">Packing Z</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

A minha ideia é que a pessoa clique em um option e seja redirecionada para uma outra pagina. Até ai beleza, está funcionando.

Porém na outra pagina que eu estou redirecionando tem uma query, por exemplo:

```
select * from tabela where linha = 'valor do option da outra pagina';
```

ou seja se a pessoa escolher assembly1 com value 1 a query ficaria assim:

```
select * from tabela where linha = '1';
```

se a pessoa escolher 2

```
select * from tabela where linha = '2';
```

esse valor jogaria numa variável `$linha = $_POST['select-native-fc'];`

O problema é que eu não estou usando form. Sei que a outra opção é ajax, mas eu sou iniciante em ajax e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso sem formulário.

Comment: Olá Daniel seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, é interessante dá uma lida no tour pra saber como funciona as regras no site. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Você pode passar no endereço do redirecionamento: `window.location="time1.php?select-native-fc=" + val` no PHP vc vai receber, `$_GET['select-native-fc']`

Comment: leandro valeu deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar o valor na url do redirecionamento:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#select-native-fc").change(function(){ 
        var val = $("#select-native-fc").val(); 
        if($(".assy") && val == "1"){
            //alert("teste");
            window.location="time1.php?select-native-fc=" + val;
        }
    }); 
});
```

E no PHP você recupera este valor fazendo sua consulta no banco.